# Add syntax highlighting to [mongodb] questions & answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I know we can explicitly add a [syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and I've being doing it for a while on question tagged [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) using the JavaScript syntax-highlight as it makes my answers prettier and because the mongo shell is an interactive JavaScript shell for MongoDB and most answers use JavaScript.

Can we have it?

---

[Answer with syntax highlighting.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37481456/3100115)

[Answer without syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37480812/3100115)

Comment: I believe (from what I read) that SO doesn't actually implements Syntax Highlighting. It is a Google Project that anyone can contribute. If you have a request concerning this, you must go on the project and address your request there.

Comment: I mean add `lang-js` as default for [tag:mongodb]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done, this can be changed on the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mongodb/info) page by mods and CMs.  I've set the default syntax highlighting to `lang-js`.

Comment: JavaScript also does fine.